# GCC Error but VS no error

Tags: c, linux, unix, gcc

When I compile the below program it is giving me this error.

```
/tmp/ccwr6gsJ.o: In function 'main':
main.cL(.text+0xa): undefined reference to 'example'
collect2: error: Id returned 1 exit status
```

Main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "includes.h"

int main()
{
    int exampleInt = example();

    return 0;
}
```

includes.h:

```
int example();
```

includes.c:

```
#include "includes.h"

int example()
{
    int i = 3;

    return i;
}
```

It seems to work in Visual Studio but not on GCC on Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is very likely a build error, i.e. you're calling the compiler on the wrong set(s) of files, and/or not doing a linking step.

Try:

```
$ gcc -o myprog main.c example.c
```

Note that a mere `#include` in a C file *does not* in any way tell the compiler to compile more C files.